# My Ftp Custom Provider is not invoked

Tags: authentication, iis, logging, ftp, provider

I've gone through all steps in tutorial on IIS Website, how create my own custom Ftp Logging/Authentication Provider. Unfortunately, it doesn't work still. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this problem for past few days. And I finally got it.

Sometimes it doesn't work at all. Sometimes, it works for a while and suddenly, after few changes in code [or somewhere else] it stops and you can't find out what happened [that was in my case].

To solve my problem [and, I believe, many others] helps me this article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2012/08/28/troubleshooting-custom-ftp-providers-with-etw.aspx

It's pretty hard to google, but value of tool from article is enormous.
I hope you can find and solve your problem with it, too.

Comment: Great resource you linked to.